# Error: Expected template-name before ‘<’ token in C++

Tags: c++, list, templates

I got the error in the title wich cause a lot of other error and I really don't know how to solve it, the error starts when I tried to declare a list ListeTriee in the main, before that i didn't have any issue with that.

**Errors**:

```
In file included from Cours.h:10:0,
                 from ListeBase.h:13,
                 from ListeBase.cxx:1:
Liste.h:12:51: error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token
 template<typename T> class Liste: public ListeBase<T>
                                                   ^
Liste.h:12:51: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘<’ token
Liste.h:12:51: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token
In file included from ListeBase.h:13:0,
                 from ListeBase.cxx:1:
Cours.h:19:20: error: field ‘groupes’ has incomplete type
         Liste<int> groupes;
                    ^
Cours.h: In member function ‘void Cours::insererGroupe(int)’:
Cours.h:28:13: error: ‘groupes’ was not declared in this scope
             groupes.insere(val);
```

The files are :

**ListeBase.h**:

```
#ifndef LISTE_BASE
#define LISTE_BASE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

#include "Timing.h"
#include "Professeur.h"
#include "Groupe.h"
#include "Local.h"
#include "Cours.h"

template<typename T> struct Cellule
{
    T valeur ;
    Cellule<T> *suivant ;
    Cellule(T v, Cellule<T> *s) : valeur(v), suivant(s) {};
};

template<typename T> class Iterateur;
template<typename T> class ListeBase
{
    protected:
        Cellule<T> *pTete ;
    public:
        ListeBase();
        ~ListeBase();
        bool estVide() const;
        int getNombreElements() const;
        void Affiche() const;
        virtual T* insere(const T & val)=0;
                friend class Iterateur<T>;
};

#endif
```

**Liste.h**

```
#ifndef LISTE
#define LISTE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

#include "ListeBase.h"
#include "Timing.h"

template<typename T> class Liste: public ListeBase<T>
{
    public:
        T* insere(const T & val);
};
#endif
```

**Cours.h**

```
#ifndef COURS
#define COURS

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include "Liste.h"
#include "Event.h"
#include "Professeur.h"
#include "Groupe.h"

class Cours: public Event
{
    private:
        char* professeur;
        Liste<int> groupes;
    public:
        Cours();
        Cours(const Cours &);
        ~Cours();
        const char* getProfesseur() const;
        void setProfesseur(Professeur &);
        void insererGroupe(int val)
        {
            groupes.insere(val);
        }
        void Affiche();
};
#endif
```

Thank you, if you need more details just ask.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg This is the correct answer. Can you type it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a circular dependency: `Cours.h` depends on `Liste.h` which depends on `ListeBase.h` which depends on `Cours.h` which depends on. `Liste.h`...

I don't see any reason for `Cours.h` to be included in `ListeBase.h`, so simply don't include it there. You should not include header files you don't actually need, and IMHO you should not include header files in header files at all if it can be avoided, Instead include all needed header files in the source files in the order needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I already tried to remove the include of Cours.h from ListeBase.h butI had errors because of the templates and thanks to you I thought to inlude it in ListeBase.cxx and ii works !